# Delay an method call without retaining the target

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class that needs to perform a method at regular intervals (say once a minute). However I do not want this to affect the life cycle of the target. In other words I do not want the target to be retained while waiting. The solution does not need to be thread safe as it will only be called on the main thread. My solution so far uses a proxy  to indicate if the class is still functional. The proxy is not tied to the life cycle of the class. Here's the code:

```
//BCDeathTag is the proxy for indicating the objects state
@interface BCDeathTag : NSObject
@property(readwrite, nonatomic, assign) BOOL isDead;
@end

@implementation BCDeathTag
@synthesize isDead = _isDead;
@end


//BCInterestingClass is where the interesting stuff happens
@interface BCInterestingClass : NSObject
@property(readonly, nonatomic) BCDeathTag *deathTag;
-(void)scheduleConsistencyCheck;
-(void)performConsistencyCheck;
...
@end

@implementation BCInterestingClass

@synthesize deathTag = _deathTag;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _deathTag = [BCDeathTag new];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    _deathTag.isDead = YES;
    [_deathTag release];

    [super dealloc];
}


-(void)scheduleConsistencyCheck
{
    __block BCInterestingClass* me = self; //prevent the block from retaining self
    BCDeathTag *deathTag = self.deathTag; //but do retain the deathTag

    double delayInSeconds = 60;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if (deathTag.isDead == NO) 
        {
            [me performConsistencyCheck];
        }
    });
}



-(void)performConsistencyCheck
{
    //Do work here
    //...
    [self scheduleConsistencyCheck]; //repeat the check
}

@end
```

`BCDeathTag` could be replaced with an `NSLock`, but `NSLock` would be more expensive and would not indicate intend as clearly.

Is this a sane solution? Am I overlooking a standard pattern or existing class/functionality within Cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is essentially zeroing weak references.

A slightly improved design by replacing `BCDeathTag` (Mondays clearly bring out my morbid side) with `BCObjectProxy`:

```
@interface BCObjectProxy : NSObject
@property(readwrite, nonatomic, assign) id target;
@end

@implementation BCObjectProxy
@synthesize target;
@end


//BCInterestingClass is where the interesting stuff happens
@interface BCInterestingClass : NSObject
@property(readonly, nonatomic) BCObjectProxy *proxy;
-(void)scheduleConsistencyCheck;
-(void)performConsistencyCheck;
...
@end

@implementation BCInterestingClass

@synthesize proxy = _proxy;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _proxy = [BYObjectProxy new];
        _proxy.target = self;
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    _proxy.target = nil;
    [_proxy release];

    [super dealloc];
}


-(void)scheduleConsistencyCheck
{
    BCObjectProxy *proxy = self.proxy;

    double delayInSeconds = 60;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        BCInterestingClass *me = proxy.target;
        [me performConsistencyCheck];
    });
}



-(void)performConsistencyCheck
{
    //Do work here
    //...
    [self scheduleConsistencyCheck]; //repeat the check
}

@end
```

It would also be possible for `BCObjectProxy` to subclass `NSProxy` instead of `NSObject`. The disadvantage of `NSProxy` is that its an abstract class and does not have an `init` method, adding one would double the implementation size of `BCObjectProxy`.